# How do i Return null or matching xml node as Object in C#

Tags: c#, xml, methods, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I got a xml structure as below:

```
<Users>
<User Code="1" Roles="1,2,3" />
</Users>
```

I provide a method to search the xml file for retrieving particular user based on code like below

```
    string xpath = "Users/User[@Code="+ Code +"]";
    XmlNode user = _xmlDatabase.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
    if (user != null)
    {
        XmlAttributeCollection userMeta = user.Attributes;
        if (userMeta != null)
        {
            int code = int.Parse(Code);
            User userInstance = new User(Code, userMeta[1].Value, userMeta[2].Value);
            return userInstance;
        }
    }
```

i would invoke the method like so
`User user = GetUserByCode("1");` & `_xmlDatabase` is a instance of `XmlDocument` class. Here is the question,

- I get to return null when no matching user is found
- Attributes i search for does not exists
- It's a fresh file

Hence i modified the method to return `"null"`only to be complained by compiler that **`"return statement is missing"`**

I kind of wanted the end-user to do

```
User user = GetUserByCode("1");
if(user == null)
  Display "No User Found"
```

Comment: If you show your entire method, rather than just a snippet that doesn't include method signature or the `return null` line, then might be able to help.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst thanks but i already accepted an answer. The code in there is what i had to put for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see the comments on below code

```
   if (user != null) // if user == null nothing will return 
    {
        XmlAttributeCollection userMeta = user.Attributes;
        if (userMeta != null) // if userMeta == null nothing will return 
        {
            int code = int.Parse(Code);
            User userInstance = new User(Code, userMeta[1].Value, userMeta[2].Value);
            return userInstance;
        }
    }
```

you can solve this as below

```
public User GetUserByCode(string Code)
{
    User userInstance = null;
    string xpath = "Users/User[@Code="+ Code +"]";
    XmlNode user = _xmlDatabase.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
    if (user != null)
    {
        XmlAttributeCollection userMeta = user.Attributes;
        if (userMeta != null)
        {
            int code = int.Parse(Code);
            userInstance = new User(Code, userMeta[1].Value, userMeta[2].Value);
        }
    }

    return userInstance;
}
```

Above code will return  null or userInstance in any case.

Comment: that was easy, simple things get unnoticed when we advanced into the subject. thanks